# Получение модуля числа без операции сравнения

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Берем простой код:

```
void main() {
    int x = abs(-1);
}
```

Собираем и дизассемблируем его:

```
$ gcc sample.c -o sample && objdump -d ./sample
```

Получаем листинг, где нет условной команды:

```
80483a1:    e8 ee ff ff ff          call   8048394 <some>
80483a6:    89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
80483a8:    c1 fa 1f                sar    $0x1f,%edx
80483ab:    31 d0                   xor    %edx,%eax
80483ad:    29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
```

Как на C/C++ получить абсолютное значение целого числа без операции сравнения?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ассемблерная операция sar это обычный сдвиг вправо.
Вот ваш код:

```
int myabs(int x)
{
    //mov    %eax,%edx
    //sar    $0x1f,%edx
    int minus_flag = x>>0x1F;//0x1F = 31

    //xor    %edx,%eax
    int y =  minus_flag ^ x;

    //sub    %edx,%eax
    y -=minus_flag;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: принято

Answer (score 4):

Я лучше ориентируюсь в Java, поэтому чтобы не выглядить глупо код не буду писать на C :)
Но с алгоритмической точки зрения это должно выглядеть примерно так:

(Я полагаю, на С/С++ представление знакового целого сделано с помощью [дополнительного кода](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)))

1. Скопировать куда-нибудь первый бит.
2. Создать новую целую переменную такого же размера.
3. Скопировать во все биты второго числа значение сохранённого ранее бита.
4. Применить побитовое "исключающее или" первого числа ко второму (XOR).
5. Прибавить к получившемуся числу значение сохранённого ранее бита.

Приведу таблицу действий для чисел -5 и 3 которые хранятся в 8 битах.

число1 доп.число1 доп.бит1 число2 доп.число2 доп.бит2

1. 11111011 00000000 1 00000011 00000000 0
2. 11111011 00000000 1 00000011 00000000 0
3. 11111011 11111111 1 00000011 00000000 0
4. 00000100 11111111 1 00000011 00000000 0
5. 00000101 11111111 1 00000011 00000000 0

Алгоритм не супер, но он без сравнений :)

Answer (score 3):

Первое, что пришло на ум, сразу после прочтения вопроса, - это взять квадратный корень из квадрата числа:

```
sqrt(x*x)
```

Другой вариант - это, как уже здесь отмечалось, воспользоваться знаниями о представлении числа и [дополнительном коде](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%29) и побитовыми операциями.

Пример для 8-битных чисел

```
char x = -5;
char minus = (x & 0x80) >> 7;            // равно 1 если x - отрицательное и 0 если положительное
char plus = (((x & 0x80) >> 7) + 1) & 1; // наоборот, равно 1, если x - положительное, и 0 если отрицательное
char abs_x = minus * (-x) + plus * x;
```

Для int будет сложнее, т.к. нужно будет учитывать кучу особенностей, например, разрядность (int может быть 8, 16, 32, 64-разрядной) и [порядок байтов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big-endian) (Little-Endian/Big-Endian).

Comment: Не забываем о том, как вычисляется корень, который как минимум будет содержать проверку на неотрицательность, умножение в задаче на битовую арифметику тоже не уместно

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритмический трюк, на котором основано вычисление модуля без ветвлений, заключается в свойстве дополнительного кода. Операция xor с числом -1 даёт инвертирование битов числа, а прибавление 1 завершает переход к отрицанию числа. Причем само число -1 получается как знаковый сдвиг вправо исходного числа, если оно было отрицательным. Если же число было положительным, что сдвиг даст 0, поэтому xor и sub ничего не изменят. Подробнее о подобных алгоритмах вычисления модуля и о скорости их работы можно прочитать [здесь](http://zealcomputing.ru/besedy/017/).