# Побитовые операции - о каких из них полезно знать программистам "более высоких" уровней?

Tags: битовые-операции, java, c, оптимизация, алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Задаю этот вопрос скорее для самообразования, чем из реальной сиюминутной необходимости:

**Что нужно знать программистам "более высоких уровней" о побитовых операциях? О каких конкретных случаях их применения желательно знать в любом случае? Приведите примеры из вашей практики, когда использования побитовых операций существенно ускоряло/упрощало?/улучшало ваш код?**

---

**Что я уже знаю:**

- Я знаю о [битовых масках](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).
- знаю, что "x & 1" проверяет чётность числа (например, [здесь, ответ @avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/100851/c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8))
- знаю про [побитовые сдвиги](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3) и умножение/деление на степени двойки.

Также я прочитал все топики на эту тему здесь на ХэшКоде и основные на StackOverflow, нашёл вот этот интересный ресурс: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Также я наслышан об [удивительном решении задачи нахождения Fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

И наслышан о книге [Hacker's Delight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201914654), которую пока что не читал. Она же [на русском](http://www.rsdn.ru/res/book/prog/worren.xml).

---

В дополнение к вопросу напишу, что кроме битовых масок (которые я уже давно использую) из всего того, что мне встретилось, единственным более-менее полезным для себя и своей *повседневной практики* я нашёл лишь только проверку числа на чётность, что навело меня на мысль, что наверняка должны быть какие-то ещё диковинные случаи, когда использование битовых операций уместно и даже желательно.

И ещё напишу, что интересуюсь этим вопросом сугубо с практической стороны, поэтому скорее буду признателен за простые примеры и реальный опыт, чем за сухие ссылки на "6 том всемирного собрания алгоритмов из какого-нибудь Великого британского учебного учреждения" и всё в таком духе.

Спасибо))

---

**Перечень интересных ссылок на смежные темы**

[Получение модуля числа без операции сравнения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[Do bitwise operators (other than shifts) make any mathematical sense in base-10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319974/do-bitwise-operators-other-than-shifts-make-any-mathematical-sense-in-base-10)

Comment: Не знаю, какие тут поставить правильные тэги, поэтому, если кто знает, - пожалуйста, переставьте.

Comment: IMHO, ограничивать свои знания "повседневной практикой" - путь в никуда. Это так же глупо, как и спрашивать "какой язык программирования мне выучить, чтобы сразу взяли на работу с пожизненной зарплатой в стопицот" :)

Comment: Уважаемый @klopp, обратите внимание, что я написал о своём предпочтении, а не о возможном ограничении качества и формата ответов. Надеюсь, что по тому, как я сформулировал свой вопрос, должно быть видно, что понимание того, о чём вы пишете, присутствует в моём сознании (ну а если нет - уж поверьте, что присутствует!)). Буду рад, если тоже поделитесь чем-нибудь интересным, даже если это тот самый шестой том собрания...

Comment: @Михаил М, а причем здесь *оптимизация*?

 (Метка вопроса, на которую Вы заменили метку *программирование*)

Comment: Зашёл, чтобы порекомендовать bit twiddling hacks. :)

---
Туда же: `x & (1 << (BITSIZE - 1))` проверяет знак числа (`BITSIZE` есть размер числа в битах, то есть `sizeof(x) * 8`).

Comment: @VladD, главное не использовать этот способ, скажем, в `if`. Все же 

    if (x < 0)
      expr(x);

очевидней (и думаю не медленнее), чем

    if (x & (1LL << ((sizeof(x) << 3) - 1)))
      expr(x);

Comment: @avp: По идее, `(1LL << ((sizeof(x) << 3) - 1))` есть константа времени компиляции, но конечно сравнивать знак таким образом нужно лишь в том редком случае, когда кровь из носу необходимо избежать ветвления.

Comment: @avp, потому что битовые операции используются в основном для оптимизации. Разве нет? Метка программирование, по-моему, в принципе на ХэшКод не нужна

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Битовые операции обычно нужны лишь для экстремальной оптимизации. В обычных случаях можно обходиться без них. В обычных случаях битовые трюки затрудняют понимание кода, применяйте их только если они вам осознано необходимы. Учтите, что современные компиляторы довольно умны, и применяют битовые трюки самостоятельно. Многие программисты, к сожалению, злоупотребляют низкоуровневыми оптимизациями, что вредит качеству кода: код становится очень сложным в поддержке, хрупким, и подверженным тонким ошибкам.

С другой стороны, раз уж битовые операции так часто используются, стоит их знать, чтобы уметь корректно читать и понимать чужой код.

Для работы с упакованными значениями в C (и C++), например, обычно лучше использовать не сдвиги и маски, а [битовые поля](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). О нужных величинах сдвига позаботится сам компилятор. В C (и кажется [в C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11996970/276994)) для выделения старшего и младшего полубайта лучше использовать такую структуру:

```
typedef union LH
{
    char c;
    struct { char h:4; char l:4; };
} LH;
```

(учтите, стандарт не даёт гарантий правильности этого, так как, например, нет гарантий, что байт содержит *в точности* 8 бит).

Важный частный случай, в котором нужны битовые операции — массив бит (например, вы хотите использовать *реально много* булевых значений, и хотите пожертвовать скоростью ради выигрыша в размере структуры данных. Для этого вы можете завести большой массив `char`'ов, и адресовать в нём биты следующим образом:

```
// 8 бит на байт => делим на 8, чтобы получить номер бпйта
inline char& Carrier(int n) { return payload[n >> 3]; }

// выделяем бит в байте: маска из трёх младших битов есть 0b111 = ((1 << 3) - 1)
// 1 << x даёт число с одним взведённым битом
inline int Bit(int n)
{
    const int threeBitMask = (1 << 3) - 1);
    int bitNumber = n & threeBitMask;
    return 1 << bitNumber;
}

inline bool GetBit(int n)
{
    return Carrier(n) & Bit(n);
}

inline void SetBit(int n, bool value)
{
    if (value)
        Carrier(n) |= Bit(n);
    else
        Carrier(n) &= ~Bit(n);
}
```

(не уверен на 100% в правильности кода). С другой стороны, это уже сделано один раз за нас, в C++ есть [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), изобретать велосипед не стоит.

Ещё один важный частный случай — это реализация алгоритмов наподобие криптографических, которые сами оперируют с битовыми представлениями чисел. Здесь, конечно, без битовой арифметики не обойтись.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, обратите внимание, отличный ответ!

Comment: @avp: спасибо!

Comment: >Битовые операции обычно нужны лишь для экстремальной оптимизации



Экстремальной-не экстремальной, но всё-таки лучше этот инструмент в своём арсенале иметь. За исключением, скажем так, совсем уж прикладных задач (небольших сайтов и т.п.). Не будет большого прока от программиста, который говорит "я не лезу в битовые операции, аллокаторы, многопоточности и индексы в БД, это всё от лукавого, надо просто машину побыстрее купить" и "кому нужны кучи сортировок, есть библиотечный quick sort, а всё остальное компилятор сделает" и т.д.



По всём остальным пунктам поддерживаю.

Comment: @Михаил М ну насчёт "машину побыстрее купить" было сказано восемь лет назад: обломайтесь! http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lin/cs380p/Free_Lunch.pdf

Comment: @alexlz, это да :) . Тем не менее, подход чуть более, чем популярен. Всё-таки, в сегодняшние 3 ГГц можно впихнуть очень много, даже не заморачиваясь с производительностью

Comment: @Михаил М: У меня обычно, если запустить профайлер, получается, что самый критичный по скорости кусок находится в совершенно неожиданном (для меня) месте. И если его переписать, программа сразу становится существенно шустрее.

Всё это, разумеется, ни в коем случае не отменяет использование подходящих структур данных (а не `std::vector` для всего с линейным поиском), оптимальных хотя бы по асимптотике алгоритмов, и здравого смысла: если где-то можно соптимизировать, _не ухудшив_ читабельность программы и не нарушив её семантику, почему не сделать?

Comment: @VladD, ну это нормально :) . И не противоречит тому, что я написал

Answer (score 20):

Самая главная (для меня естественно) битовая операция это `XOR` - *исключающее или*. Операция `XOR` замечательна тем, что применения 2 раза к одному и тому же битовому массиву восстанавливает ее исходное значени именно это ее свойство активно применяется в операциях шифрования:

```
C = A xor B //кодирование с помощью вектора B
A = C xor B //восстановление исходного значения
```

Более [подробно здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)

Вторая по значимости (опять таки для меня) операция `AND` - часто применяется для "выцепления" из длинной битовой последовательности конкретной части. Ну например есть `long`, который надо расщепить на два `int`'а. Другой пример: есть длинная битовая последовательность, которую скажем, возвращает какой-нить дурацкий контроллер не менее дурацкого устройства, в мануале сказано, что 3-й бит показывает готовность устройства. Берем битовую маску где в 3-й позиции забита единичка (4), а все остальное 0, накладываем на битовый массив и проверяем > 0:

```
if( (bitsFromController & 4) > 0)
   //ready!
```

Ну про битовые сдвижки вы уже сами все написали, так что повторяться не буду.

А `OR` это просто сложение двух битовых массивов.

**Update**

Примерчик c битами конвертация байта в 16-тиричную строку (Java):

```
 /* по сути надо входной байт разделить на два 4-х битовых элемента */
 public String byteToHex(byte b) { //допустим конвертим 76=01001100
    final String HEX="0123456789ABCDEF";
    char[] val=new char[2];
    val[0]=HEX.charAt(b >>> 4);    //убиваем 4 младших бита получаем 4=0100
    val[1]=HEX.charAt(b & 15);     // накладываем маску (15=00001111) на 4 младших бита получаем 12=1100
    return String.valueOf(val); //возвращаем 4C=76
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень ценно и интересно. Хотелось бы ещё больше! Есть ли что-то ещё для уровней чуть повыше, чем работа с контроллерами? ;)

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich см. апдейт

Comment: Вижу апдейт, но не понимаю его. Извините за неосведомлённость (как раз и заполняю многочисленные пробелы), но можно построчно прокомментировать - что делает `b & 0xff` и что такое оператор `>>>`?

Comment: `>>>` - это также сдвиг. 
` b & 0xff ` - это взять по модулю 256. оно же самый младший байт.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich см. комментарии по коду `>>>` - это беззнаковая сдвижка вправо

Comment: Спасибо, немного понятнее))

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, в Java нет беззнаковых целых и поэтому есть операция беззнакоаого сдвига вправо.

Смотрите в Си

    char b = 0xaa;
    printf ("%d %d\n", b >> 4, (unsigned char)b >> 4);

    // вывод: -6 10

разницу между сдвигом вправо числа со знаком и без него (unsigned char).

Comment: О! Спасибо за разъяснение! Признаться честно, я всё равно не до конца понимаю пример, но оставляю себе с ним разобраться в качестве домашнего задания.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich это вы себе еще мозг не разрушили избыточным знанием по-поводу [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - по русски говоря порядком следования старших и младших байтов в разных осях. Да и форма представления отрицательных чисел в разных системах - это тоже с непривычки может нарушить сон и покой :)

Comment: `XOR`, к сожалению, явно недооценён. Спасибо, что упомянули.

Answer (score 10):

И никто до сих пор не вспомнил про флаги и перечисления?

Например, мы хотим записать в переменную некоторое множество дней недели (здесь и далее - C#)

```
enum WeekDayMask
{
    None = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8, 
    Friday = 16,
    Saturday = 32,
    Sunday = 64
}
```

Теперь все выходные можно записать как :

```
var holidays = WeekDayMask.Saturday | WeekDayMask.Sunday;
```

Проверить что день - выходной

```
var isHoliday = day & holidays != WeekDayMask.None;
```

Comment: Это да, но семантичнее использовать `HashSet<WeekDay>`.

А ещё вы забыли атрибут `[Flags]`.

Comment: например, `Date::Calendar - Calendar objects for different holiday schemes`

руками такое вычислять - гореть в аду.

Comment: @VladD HashSet<WeekDay> как раз создает лишний объект и кучу оверхеда. Здесь же просто int32. [Flags] IIRC - только меняет поведение ToString(). HasFlag не использовал для наглядности битовых операций под капотом.

@klopp Дни недели - пример комбинирования значений.

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло: Об этом я как раз и говорю как о нарушении семантики в угоду нанооптимизации. Разумеется, если ваша программа работает с миллионами дат, дни недели можно так оптимизировать. Если дат одна-две, смысла в потере семантики я честно говоря не вижу.

Насчёт `[Flags]` — да, но если уж приводить пример, то хороший.

Comment: Семантика тут почти не теряется, мы так же работаем с множеством значений, только теперь не методом Add а символом |. Также HashSet не эквивалентен перечислению, поскольку перечисление - valueType. Плюс решение с перечислением удобно для хранения в бд, передаче в бинарном виде. И зачем мучать систему почти бесконечным оверхедом (битовые операции, можно сказать, бесплатные) в угоду сомнительного выигрыша в семантике?

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло: Выигрыш в семантике НИКОГДА не бывает сомнительным. Это исходный пункт любого недетского программирования.

Теперь по мелочам. По поводу хранения в БД смешно: не дело базы данных диктовать структуру данных. Layer сериализации пусть выбирает адекватное представление, программе-то какое дело до этого? Ну и заставлять того, кто читает код, выучить, что для наборов месяцев или там лет надо пользоваться `Add`, а для дня недели всё по-другому, неправильно и чревато тонкими багами. (Например, кто-то сделает extension method `Add(WeekDay, int)`.)

Comment: Ну семантика, так семантика, вот не поверю что 

    var holidays = WeekDayMask.Saturday | WeekDayMask.Sunday;

читается сложнее и менее очевидно чем

    var holidays = new HashSet<WeekDay> { WeekDay.Saturday , WeekDay.Sunday };

Также недетское программирование не заключается в написании программ, у которых 90% времени уходит на перекладывание данных из одного слоя в другой и сборкой мусора после этих перекладываний.

И если уж флаги - это зло и говнокодерство, то почему они есть в свежем апи [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx

Comment: @VladD вообще хеш-множества и битовые множества семантически сильно разные. Разумеется, это подход с точки зрения реализации, но уж настолько абстрагироваться, мне кажется, не стоит. Особливо если HashSet будет инициировать своппинг (плотно заполненное множество большого размера)

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло: Конечно, не заключается, но я этого и не говорил. Для того, чтобы делать что-то продуктивное, программа должна иметь удобные структуры данных, а общение с layer'ом сериализации должно быть, очевидно, пренебрежимо малым по сравнению с основной логикой.

Флаги хороши там, где они уместны. Для файловых систем и их аналогов программисты _привыкли_ к флагам, поэтому MS предоставила им привычное API. Хотя семантичнее был бы объект-контейнер настроек (они вполне могут быть и не бинарными) + пресеты.

@alexlz: Своппинг? На современных машинах?

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужна сейчас на работе

Answer (score 6):

Когда приходится конвертировать картинки между форматами с разной цветовой глубиной, битовые операции помогают обрабатывать по несколько пикселов за раз. Допустим, надо сконвертировать (с дополнением нулями) 4 4-битных значения в 4 8-битных: 0xabcd -> 0xa0b0c0d0. Это можно сделать как-нибудь так (а возможно и побыстрее):

```
v2 = ((v << 8) | v) & 0x00FF00FF;    // 0xab00cd
v = ((v2 << 4) | v2) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
```

4 байта - не очень много, но на MMX/SSE всё то же самое, но регистры 64-128-битные.

Сходными трюками я, например, делал создание сияния вокруг объектов (на обычном двумерном растре). Хотя самым трудным в том случае было выбрать, сколько пикселов лучше запихнуть в одну ячейку. В итоге выбрал средний вариант (4 в одном int'e) и сделал предварительный расчёт всех возможных масок для всех 16-ти вариантов пикселов в int'e (каждый исходный пиксел у меня либо создавал сияние, либо нет).

Comment: @Михаил М: кстати, вычисление графических эффектов на лету — отличный пример _нужной_ «экстремальной» оптимизации.

Comment: Я под экстремальной подразумевал подгонку под конкретный процессор, что-нибудь такое, а Вы? 



Граф. эффекты - один из множества типов задач, объём работы в которых достаточно большой и потому желательно посидеть над кодом, подумать, и ускорить его в несколько раз за счёт использования оптимальных структур/перестановки операторов/битовых операций/... А если какие-нибудь совсем жёсткие требования, встроенный процессор с ограниченной мощностью, в который нужно втиснуть решение, или там задачи, которые будут считаться месяцами, то тут уже место для экстрем. оптим. ради дополнительных десятков %

Comment: @Михаил М: хороший вопрос. Ну, это такая оптимизация, где _необходимо_ выжимать последние капли производительности, может быть даже в ущерб понятности или красоте кода.

Comment: @VladD, т.е. примерно как я выше написал? Тогда не готов согласиться, что битовые операции нужны в основном для этого. ИМХО, "человеческие" оптимизации - гораздо более часто нужны, проще и эффективнее (в смысле соотношения усилий/ускорение), чем экстремальные. И битовые операции подпадают скорее под категорию "человеческих". Конечно, не всегда возможно это сделать без потери понятности и т.п. кода, но это относится практически к любой оптимизации