# Оператор | (ИЛИ) при передаче флагов в метод

Tags: java, android

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Вот кусок кода. Метод `setFlags` на вход получает `int`, но никак не boolean. Что значить оператор ИЛИ между двумя константами при передаче в метод?

Comment: это битовая операция, а не логическая

Comment: [Побитовые операции - о каких из них полезно знать программистам “более высоких” уровней?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/281650/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`|` - это *побитовое* ИЛИ над целочисленными операндами и *логическое* ИЛИ над булевыми операциями.
`||` - это *логическое* ИЛИ над булевыми операндами (при этом правый операнд будет вычислен, только если левый вычислялся как `false`).

Побитовое ИЛИ часто используют при работе с флагами, упакованными в целочисленное значение. Каждому флагу соответствует число вида `2^n`. В двоичном представлении это будет одна единица с `n` нолей слева:

```
0x01 == 0b00000001
0x02 == 0b00000010
0x04 == 0b00000100
0x08 == 0b00001000
...
0x80 == 0b10000000
```

Для получения битовой маски, соответствующей объединению (включению) нескольких флагов, их складывают при помощи побитового ИЛИ.

```
0b00000001 | 0b00001000 == 0b00001001
```

Для проверки, включен ли конкретный флаг, используют побитовое И. Если результат ненулевой - флаг включен:

```
((0b00001001 & 0b00001000) != 0) // true, флаг включен
((0b00001001 & 0b01000000) != 0) // false, флаг выключен
```

Comment: Эх, раньше просто юзал это и не задумывался. А там вон какие сложные штуки)

Comment: На самом деле в Java оба оператора ( | и || ) могут быть логическими. Первый значит безусловную проверку всех частей логического выражения, второй упрощенную, в которой если результат можно получить не вычисляя все части, это вычесление не будет производится. То, какая операция будет выполнена (логическая или побитовая), зависит от операндов (булевые или численные)

Comment: @pavlofff оператор | над логическими операндами хоть и выдаёт такой же результат как и ||, но тем не менее это все таки остаётся побитовой операцией, а не логической, просто у логических операндов всего один бит значащий.

Comment: @xkor Да, я больше к тому, что в ответе в скобках указано - "*| - это побитовое ИЛИ (операция над целочисленными операндами)*", а это не так, к логическим операндам `|` тоже вполне применим.

Comment: @pavlofff, специально не хотел углубляться в особенности логических ленивых/неленивых операций, т.к. вопрос про битовые маски. Но раз вы настаиваете - дополнил вопрос, чтобы избежать неточности.

Comment: @xkor, нет, JLS явно говорит, что в случае с булевыми операндами это логическая операция, а не побитовая (boolean не приводится к int при вычислении). Хотя по внешним проявлениям это выглядит именно так.

Comment: Я помню, когда сам выяснял этот вопрос, такие "недосказанности" ставили в тупик. В одном источнике одно, в другом - другое, так что лучше все же сделать на этом акцент. Офф. документация все же [однозначно относит |](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) к побитовым операторам, хотя в свете того, что в Java *false/true* не является *0/1*, а самостоятельный тип все это создает некоторый разброд и шатание :)

Comment: @pavlofff в JLS в главе  *15.22.2 Boolean **Logical** Operators &, ^, and |* говорится, что это ***bitwise** operator* ) Так и живем.

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае используется ["побитовое или"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Как следует из название оно используется как обычное или только для битов числа.

В данном случае оно используется для того чтобы установить одновременно оба флага.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень интересное решение. Не знал.