# Удалить один атрибут (скажем, "только для чтения") у файла?

Tags: c#, файлы

Предположим, у файла есть следующие атрибуты: `ReadOnly, Hidden, Archived, System`.

Как я могу снять только один из них, скажем ReadOnly?

Если я использую следующий код, он снимает ВСЕ атрибуты:

```
IO.File.SetAttributes("File.txt",IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to remove a single Attribute (e.g. ReadOnly) from a File?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7399611/5752652) от участника  [@MilMike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82460/milmike).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7399611/5752652

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить именно `ReadOnly` то его проще всего снять следующим кодом:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToAFile);
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
```

В общем случае код для манипулирования одним конкретным атрибутом выглядит примерно следующим образом (см. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx)):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

        // Create the file if it exists.
        if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            File.Create(path);
        }

        FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);

        if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        {
            // Make the file RW
            attributes = RemoveAttribute(attributes, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            File.SetAttributes(path, attributes);
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is no longer RO.", path);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Make the file RO
            File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is now RO.", path);
        }
    }

    private static FileAttributes RemoveAttribute(FileAttributes attributes, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
    {
        return attributes & ~attributesToRemove;
    }
}
```

<sub>Использованы свободные переводы ответов [How to remove a single Attribute (e.g. ReadOnly) from a File?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087431/5752652) от участника  [@sll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485076/sll) и [How to remove a single Attribute (e.g. ReadOnly) from a File?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087431/5752652) от участника  [@Preet Sangha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30225/preet-sangha).</sub>

Update Дополнительно рекомендую почитать по теме битовых операций вот эти вопросы на ru so:

- [Побитовые операции - о каких из них полезно знать программистам "более высоких" уровней?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/281650/213987)
- [Оператор | (ИЛИ) при передаче флагов в метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/558673/213987)