# Проверка нечетности через битовые операции

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, функции, linq

Есть статический метод:

```
public class Application
{
    public static bool IsOdd(int i)
    {
        return ((i & 1) == 1);
    }
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста как работает эта строка: return ((i & 1) == 1);
Понимаю что она возвращает true или false, & тоже понятно что такое, но как работает код в скобках не пойму.

Спасибо.

Comment: _& тоже понятно что такое_ - и что это такое?

Comment: Это логический оператор, который всегда обрабатывает оба операнда и возвращает True только в том случае, если оба оператора равны True

Comment: ты ошибаешься :) [Logical AND operator &](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-)

Comment: А что это тогда?)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Это побитные или битовые (bitwise) операции.

Comment: Обычно в c# на четность проверяют с помощью `i % 2 == 0`. Если не ошибаюсь, компилятор сам умеет это оптимизировать в битовые операции, как и обычное деление на 2.

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 5):

В скобках используются битовые операции с маской - убирается всё, кроме младшего бита.

Т.е. если в двоичном виде неважно что было на месте "x" (0 или 1) после примерения маски 0000 0001 к числу xxxx xxxy через логическое "и" гарантированно останется только младший (крайний справа) бит в своём исходном виде, остальное обнулится. Останется только 0000 000y.

```
i = xxxx xxx1      xxxx xxx0
    &&&& &&&&      &&&& &&&&
1 = 0000 0001      0000 0001
    ---- ----      ---- ----
    0000 0001 = 1  0000 0000 = 0
```

Для сравнения: это как в десятичной системе взять число 321: маска подобрана так, что остаётся только цифра 1 в младшем разряде. И типа этот остаток проверяется на не/чётность.

Почитайте по теме:

- [Побитовые операции - о каких из них полезно знать программистам "более высоких" уровней?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/281650/213987)
- [Оператор | (ИЛИ) при передаче флагов в метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/558673/213987)

Comment: Спасибо, в этой теме я действительно слаб пока

Comment: @Eminio Да ничего сложного так то. Побитовое `и` - это как логическое `и`, только берётся оно отдельно для каждого разряда двух двоичных чисел.

Comment: да дело в том, что у меня базы никакой нет теоретической в плане основ информатики, биты и прочее... Я стал сразу изучать конкретный язык, но теперь надо начинать в этом направлении двигаться...

Comment: @Eminio добавил схему в ответ, может так понятнее `&` применяется к каждому биту числа в двоичном представлении.