# Реализация перечисления с использованием оператора |

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Моя проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно реализовать возможность перечисления доступных для записи типов `Severity`, используемых в сообщениях. Это необходимо для того, чтобы иметь возможность фильтровать сообщения по степени серьезности в классе `Logger`. `Severity` является `enum` классом:

```cpp
enum class Severity: uint8_t
{
    EMERGENCY   = 0, // System is unusable
    ALERT       = 1, // Action must be taken immediately
    CRITICAL    = 2, // Critical conditions
    ERROR       = 3, // Error conditions
    WARNING     = 4, // Warning conditions
    NOTICE      = 5, // Normal but significant condition
    INFO        = 6, // Informational
    DEBUG       = 7, // Debug level messages
};
```

На данный момент я вижу только одно действующие решения этой проблемы. А решение состоит в том, чтобы иметь два открытых метода в классе `Logger`:

```cpp
void addSeverity(Severity severity);
void rmvSeverity(Severity severity);
```

которые будут отвечать за добавление и удаление типов серьезности. Например, если определенное `Severity` добавлено, игнорирование сообщений с таким типом производится не будет.

Но мне бы хотелось, иметь такую возможность, указанную в коде ниже (в данном случае, мы будем иметь возможность записывать лишь 3 типа `Severity`):

```cpp
void setSeveritySupports(Severity);

// ... 

setSeveritySupports(Severity::INFO | Severity::WARNING | Severity::ERROR);
```

Я могу перегрузить оператор `|` таким способом :

```cpp
Severity operator|(Severity l, Severity r)
{
    return Severity(static_cast<int>(l) | static_cast<int>(r));
}
```

но в таком случае, я максимум что могу, это установть максимальное значение `Severity`.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то просто используйте в качестве значений перечислителей степени двойки: 1, 2, 4, 8, ... Тогда вы сможете с помощью битового или сразу несколько флагов упаковать в одно значение. См.: [Оператор | (ИЛИ) при передаче флагов в метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/558673).

Comment: Вам именно `enum class` нужен?

Comment: Да, а enum или enum class - без разницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого?

```
enum Severity : uint8_t
{
    EMERGENCY = 0x01, // System is unusable
    ALERT     = 0x02, // Action must be taken immediately
    CRITICAL  = 0x04, // Critical conditions
    ERROR     = 0x08, // Error conditions
    WARNING   = 0x10, // Warning conditions
    NOTICE    = 0x20, // Normal but significant condition
    INFO      = 0x40, // Informational
    DEBUG     = 0x80, // Debug level messages
};

inline const char* severityToString(uint8_t sev) {
    switch (sev) {
    case EMERGENCY: return "Emergency";
    case ALERT:     return "Alert";
    case CRITICAL:  return "Critical";
    case ERROR:     return "Error";
    case WARNING:   return "Warning";
    case NOTICE:    return "Notice";
    case INFO:      return "Info";
    case DEBUG:     return "Debug";
    default:        return "";
    }
}

void setSeveritySupports(uint8_t flag) {
    uint8_t tmp = flag;
    uint8_t mask = 0x1;
    while (tmp > 0) {
        if(tmp & 1)
            cout << "Установлен флаг: " << severityToString(flag & mask) << endl;
        mask <<= 1;
        tmp >>= 1;
    }
} 

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    setSeveritySupports(Severity::ALERT | Severity::INFO | Severity::ERROR | Severity::DEBUG);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат программы:

[image: Результат]

Используем в качестве значений степени двойки, т.к. возьмем 2 числа являющиеся степенями двойки, например 64 и 8, в двоичной системе счисления они будут выглядеть так:

```
64 = ...0010000
8  = ...0000100
```

Воспользовавшись оператором `|` (побитовое ИЛИ), мы сможем упаковать эти два числа в одно.

```
64 = ...0010000 |
8  = ...0000100 =
20 = ...0010100
```

И теперь по этому числу мы сможем получить обратно число 64 и 8.

По [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558673/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4) которую предложил wololo вы можете почитать об этой теме.

P.s. Так как у вас 8 значений в `enum`, то максимальное значение будет `2^

Comment: К сожалению, я запустил ваш код, и он неправильно выводит результаты.

Comment: @bbdd конкретно что выводит? И мой код не изменяли? Проверил на разных компиляторах, вроде работает.

Comment: Конечно, как говорится, дело вкуса, но imho нагляднее задавать значения степеням двойки как `(1 << n)`, т.е. получим `ALERT = (1 << 0); .... DEBUG = (1 << 7);`

Comment: @avp не знаю, не знаю. Тогда уж `0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...` так точно наглядней, но точно не `1 << 0`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, так у вас в примере и написано 1, 2, 4, ... (какая разница hex или dec?). Мне просто лень было вводить еще один уровень имен, что-то типа ALERT_NUM = 1, ... DEBUG_NUM = 7 (подумал, что это очевидно). Т.е. в конечном виде (обычно это выглядит несколько избыточно) получите `DEBUG = (1 << DEBUG_NUM)` / И еще, лично я предпочтаю для подбных целей обычный #define ... (а не enum. (зачем плодить лишние сущности?))

Comment: @avp что? в примере значения в hex, а я даже дополнил комментарий написал `16, 32, 64`, то есть я имел в виду в десятичной системе счисления, что ну на мой взгляд проще воспринимать разве нет? Но ваш вариант это точно мимо.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, извините, а в какой области вы программируете?

Comment: @avp не имеет значения, да и я не могу дать конкретный ответ. В любом случае вы пишите "нагляднее", `1 << 0` это разве наглядней? То есть вы задаете значения в виде какого-то действия в данном случае `<<`, что уже не может быть наглядней для любого человека. Просто числа воспринимаются человек намного лучше. Если вы конечно понимаете о чем я.

Comment: Наверное, поскольку я хоть и начинал в прикладном программировании и базах, но давно уже близок к системе и железу, мне как раз наоборот, запись **(1 << n)** представляется наглядней, поскольку сразу говорит, что **за данное значение отвечает бит номер n.**

Comment: @avp ну вам так понятней,  а человек который не сталкивался с `<<` и битами, ему будет я думаю понятней в виде `1, 2, 4, 8` т.к. степень двойки еще в школе все узнают.

Comment: Печально, когда реальное представление данных в компе не очевидно для программиста

Comment: @bbdd заметил ошибку. Не было проверки на `Severity::EERGENCY`, так что изменил их значения и немного функцию, хотя можно было просто проверку на 0 сделать, но это не очень красиво

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, запустил и работает. Спасибо большое