# Заполнить битовый массив. Дописать данные к ячейке с данными. Java

Tags: java

Добрый день!

Есть следующее задание, изображенное на картинке: 
Нужно сделать массив масок для каждого элемента введенного с клавиатуры.
для символа # = это 1,  для символа . это 0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С клавиатуры мы вводим следующую последовательность:

```
Input Format:
#...#
.....
#....
.....
```

Далее нужно получить массив показанный на изображении.

Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке пройти считывания строк, после считывания первой строки мы получаем массив

```
[1,0,0,0,1]
```

Далее при считывании второй строки нам бы следовало получить массив

```
[01,00,00,01]
```

при третьем считывании

```
[101,000,000,001]
```

и при четвертом

```
[0101,0000,0000,0001]
```

Но в реальности мы не добавляем данные к ячейке массива, а переписываем ее при каждом следующем считывании данных.

```
               byte[] maskArray;
               Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
               maskArray = new byte[5];
                 for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                    String s;
                    if(s.charAt(i) == '#') {
                        byte num = 1;
                        byte a = maskArray[i];
                        byte c = (byte) (a + num); 
                        maskArray[i] = c;
                    }else if (s.charAt(i)=='.'){
                        System.out.print("0");
                        byte num = 0;
                        byte a = maskArray[i];
                        byte c = (byte) (a + num); 
                        maskArray[i] = c;
                    }
                }   
        }
```

Я понимаю что может делаю не правильно, и это скорее всего так и есть, но поставили задание разобраться в этом вопросе, а навыков работы с Java нет, только с javascript.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Всем хорошего дня!

Comment: Может попробуете подготовить [воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? В приведенном фрагменте много неясного. Куда записывается результат? Где считываются строки? Почему только одна? Почему только 4 символа? Почему биты складываются?

Comment: Как устанавливать заданный бит в маске можно посмотреть в этом вопросе, например: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/281650/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял то вот работаюший код.

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] maskArray;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    maskArray = new byte[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        String s = sc.next().trim();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) == '#')
            maskArray[i] |= 1<<j;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maskArray.length; i++)
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(maskArray[i], 2));
}
```

}

если нужно выстраивать наоборот то заменяем это

```
maskArray[i] = (byte) (maskArray[i] + Math.pow(2,j));
```

на это

```
maskArray[i] = (byte) (maskArray[i]*2 + 1);
```

На счет задания не понял. Что значит значения не задавать а добавлять.

используя i++ что ли?

Comment: Благодарю! Работает!
Есть только одна проблема.  Когда у нас ячейка массива начинается на 0 - к примеру при вводе :
..##.
Мы должны получить:
00110
А получаем :
110
т.е первые нули убираются.  Это как бы логично, но вызывает определенную проблему.  Дело в том, что мы потом должны будем использовать эту маску для побитового сравнения с другой маской.
Используя первый символ нашей маски и первый символ другой маски.
В случае, когда нули убираются - наш первый символ всегда будет первая единица. А нам нужно сохранить все нули.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Это биты байтового поля. первый бит это восьмой бит с конца который при заполнении пяти битов всегда будет нулем. 
Как вы находите первый не нулевой бит и почему? Если вам нужно что бы первые нули оставались то это вообше не нужно было превращать в байт и делать стрингом.

Comment: У меня была идея сделать стрингом, но тогда возникает вопрос как потом использовать операцию XOR(^) между двумя ячейками массивов.
Задача вообще вписать макс. кол. квадратов 2х2 в поле указанное на рисунке. Нельзя что бы квадраты пересекались  Причем знак # -  это занятое место, на него вписывать нельзя.  Один из этапов решения задачи - получение массива маски поля (для последующей работы с ним путем исп. операторов & и ^). Нули отвечают за пустой квадратик, единицы за занятый. Насколько я понимаю получив ячейку маски [0001] - мы можем потом сравнить ее с ячейкой к прим. [0101] и анализироват

Comment: Появилась идея использовать что то такого плана:
System.out.println(String.format("%03d", Integer.toString(maskArray[i],2)));
но получаю ошибку.
Если же пробую :
System.out.println(String.format("%03d", maskArray[i])  - то все ок, - нули добавляются но в ячейках запись не приведена к битовому формату данных.

Comment: Тут явно что то не так. 
1) если тебе нужны операции & | ^  ты их можешь сделать с помошью простой логики на цифрах. 
2) если тебе нужно хранить эти значения как биты байта то зачем ты переводишь их в строку.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! 
Буду стараться делать дальше, возможно не до конца разобрался в задании. Если получится - я постараюсь в этой теме отписаться что и как вышло и почему использовал биты или строки.  Пока еще сложно...