# Как получить модуль числа без использования математических библиотек?

Tags: c++, c, тернарный-оператор

Нужно получить модуль числа без использования математических библиотек и операторов `if` и `else`. Но можно использовать тернарные операторы.

Comment: "Модуль" чего именно? И какие библиотеки считаются "мат."?

Comment: опишите что именно вы именно имеете в виду....Абсолютное значение? или что?..

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/667/176217) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/781552/176217). Может даже стоит задубликатить.

Answer (score 10):

Проблем...

```
return (a<0)? -a:a;
```

Comment: Скобки не нужны

Comment: @alexolut Это принципиально? Я обычно не ставлю лишние скобки только при соревнованиях на краткость кода, во всех остальных случаях предпочитаю поставить лишнего, но чтоб уж точно работало :) Таблицу всех приоритетов на память - говорю откровенно - не помню.

Comment: видимо тернарку редко используете. Просто для меня это выглядит почти как `(((((a<0)))))? -a:a;`.

Answer (score 6):

На случай, если тернарные тоже закончатся

1. ```
   value *= (value > 0) - (value < 0);
   ```
2. ```
   value *= 1 - 2 * (value < 0);
   ```
3. Ну и просто так: для целочисленных типов - битхак, формально платформеннозависимый

   ```
   value = 
     (value ^ (value >> CHAR_BIT * sizeof value - 1))
     - (value >> CHAR_BIT * sizeof value - 1);
   ```

   Выражение в скобках повторяется, но мне просто не хотелось заводить дополнительную переменную.